# Create datatable in js via json data in a variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, datatables

now I encounter a problem. I want to use ajax to show a datatable via using data coming from sql server database. Current state is I have used ajax to call a Handler.ashx to connect sql server and convert the data to json (using newtonsoft.json). In ajax, all json data has been recevied from Handler.ashx and stored in a variable "msg" which could be successfully showed on page. I want to put this "msg" into a datatable but failed all the time. I tried almost all methods online to set the datatable but still give different errors. I want to create a datatable in js and fill in my json data. But the result is either null or no data available in table.

Here is the codes and json data looks like.

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#eventsButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Handler.ashx",
            //contentType: "application/json",
            data: { postcode: $("#eventsPostcodeTextbox").val() },
            cache: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                //for (var i in msg) {
                //  $("#eventGrid").append(msg[i]);
                //}
                //var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(msg);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = msg;
                $('#eventtable').dataTable({
                    //"paging": false,
                    //"searching": false,
                    //"retrieve": true,
                    //"bProcessing": true,

                    //"data": msg.data,
                    //"datatype": "JSON",
                    //"ajax": "HandlerAll.ashx",
                    //"aaData": JSON.parse(msg),
                    //"ajax":
                    //"dataSrc":virtualTable
                    //"aoColumns": [
                    // { "mData": "ID" },
                    // { "mData": "FESTIVAL" },
                    // { "mData": "SUBURB" },
                    // { "mData": "POSTCODE" },
                    // { "mData": "WEBSITE" },
                    // { "mData": "DESCRIPTION" }
                    // ]
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Server error.");
            }
        })
    });
});
```

json data (the size depends on the search condition, the table columns should have "ID","Festival" and so on, but no "virtualTable"):

```
{ "virtualTable": [ { "ID": "1", "FESTIVAL": "Antipodes Festival", "SUBURB": "Lonsdale Street, Melbourne", "POSTCODE": "3000", "WEBSITE": "http://www.antipodesfestival.com.au/", "DESCRIPTION": "The greek precinct in melbourne cbd will transform into a huge, free street festival with the hosting of the antipodes lonsdale street festival which will hold sway from 14 february 2015 to 15 february 2015." }, { "ID": "5", "FESTIVAL": "Boite Singers Festival", "SUBURB": "Victoria", "POSTCODE": "3000", "WEBSITE": "http://boite.com.au/index.php", "DESCRIPTION": "The boite singers festival brings you four days of vocal inspiration and sheer fun on the second weekend of january each year." } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you get a JSON as reponse, I would try to convert it to JSON object, take the virtualTable part that it is a set of records in JSON and convert it to an array to add it to my table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#eventsButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Handler.ashx",
            //  dataType: "json",
            data: { postcode: $("#eventsPostcodeTextbox").val() },
            success: function (msg) {
                 var jdata = $.parseJSON(msg);
                 jdata = jdata.virtualTable;
                 if (jdata.length != 0) {
                     var array_data = [];
                     var temp_array = [];
                     $(jdata).each(function(key, value) {
                           temp_array = [];
                           temp_array = [value.ID,
                                        value.FESTIVAL,
                                        value.SUBURB,
                                        value.POSTCODE,
                                        value.WEBSITE,
                                        value.DESCRIPTION
                                    ];
                            array_data[array_data.length] = temp_array;

                      });
                      $('#eventtable').dataTable().fnAddData(array_data);
                      $('#eventtable').dataTable().fnDraw();
                 },
              error: function (data) {
                    alert("Server error");
              }
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, it gave an error on the line $('#eventtable').dataTable().fnAddData(array_data);0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'

Comment: I added <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> on the page.

Comment: What version of datatables are you using?  I am using v1.9.4.  If you are using a most recent version, they changed the API with rows.add() instead of fnAddData().  Check the documentation of datatables about rows.add() :    http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add%28%29

Comment: Hi, I tried to use v1.9.4, but still give an error on creating dataTable().

Answer (score -1):

> **SOLUTION**

Use the code below to initialize the table:

```
$('#eventtable').dataTable({
   data: msg.virtualTable,
   columns: [
      { data: "ID" },
      { data: "FESTIVAL" },
      { data: "SUBURB" },
      { data: "POSTCODE" },
      { data: "WEBSITE" },
      { data: "DESCRIPTION" }
   ]
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv5jvrbm/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Can not fill in the table. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @GuodongRong, do you see any errors in the console? Can you please add `console.log(msg)` in `success` and post the results.

Comment: Exception was thrown at line 2, column 10673 in http://localhost:13861/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 2, column 10898 in http://localhost:13861/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 2, column 10673 in http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 2, column 10898 in http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

Comment: yes, there is some errors!! But when I alert(msg), the json data is fine.

Comment: Refresh the page to see messages that may have occurred before the F12 tools were opened. 
HTML1415: Unexpected character: U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (-) 
index.aspx, line 69 character 59
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1675115.8258740564!2d-98.4671417929578!3d34.91371150021706!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x54eab584e432360b%3A0x1c3bb99243deb742!2sUnited+States!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1434956093308 
index.aspx

Comment: I have removed the google map, but still can not put my json to datatable. In console and alert, the json data is fine.

Comment: @GuodongRong, added demo to show that my solution works. It may not work if the data structure that you return from the server is different from [this JSON](http://myjson.com/12646).